# select only certain fields if only one field value is known in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a collection **userDetails** in MongoDB that stores a document like this:

```
{
  objectid      : 'xxxxx'
  "name"        : "value",
  "email"       : "xyz@example.com" ,
  "phone"       :  123123 ,
  "age"         :  19 ,
  "gender"      :  "male"
  "description" : 'xxxx'
 }
```

Now considering I only know the user's email and no other details how would I fetch only name and phone strictly.

```
db.userDetails.find( { "email" : "xyz@example.com"  }  )
```

This returns me the entire details of the user.

So coming from MySQL background I would have queried it like this :

```
select name , phone from userDetails where email ='xyz@example.com'
```

What would be the best alternative of the above sql query in monodb ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/). The find-function has an optional second argument called "projection" which allows you to specify which fields you want.

```
db.userDetails.find( 
  { "email": "xyz@example.com" }, 
  { "_id": 0, "name": 1, "phone" : 1 }, 
)
```

Comment: @user3624993 When I was able to solve the problem, please accept the answer by clicking the tick-icon next to it.